# Why does the generalized Weierstrass theorem not apply to $\Psi(u) = \int_{-1}^1 (xu'(x))^2dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $$\Psi(u) = \int_{-1}^1 (xu'(x))^2dx$$

for $u \in \{u \in C^1[-1,1], u(-1) = 0, u(1)=1 \}$.

We have that $\Psi$ has an $\inf$ (0) but $0$ is not a $\min$. Why does Weierstrass theorem not apply?

---

Weierstrass: Let $\Phi$ be coercive and  a weakly lower semicontinuous functional on a reflexive space, then $u$ has a min.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the failure depends on the topology you are using.

- The space $X = C^1([-1,1])$ is not reflexive.
- In $X = W^{1,2}(-1,1)$, the functional is not coercive.

You can, however, work in a weighted Sobolev space:
$$X := \{v \in L^2(-1,1) \mid v|_{(-1,0)} \text{ and } v|_{(-1,0)} \text{ are weakly differentiable  and } \|v\|_{X} < \infty\},$$
where
$$\|v\|_X^2 := \|v\|_{L^2(-1,1)}^2 + \int_{-1}^0 x^2 \, v'(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d} x + \int_0^1  x^2 \, v'(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d} x.$$
In this space, your functional achieve its minimum at
$u = \chi_{(0,1)}$.

Comment: What example shows that $C^1$ is not reflexive?

Comment: And why would it not be coercive in $W^{1,2}$?

Comment: There are many possibilities to check that $C^1$ is not reflexive, e.g., its dual is not separable. You should try to figure out why the functional is not coercive in $W^{1,2}$, it is quite easy to check.

Comment: I can see that $$\int_{-1}^1 (xu'(x))^2dx \le \Vert u \Vert_{W^{1,2}},$$ (by Holder inequality) but I don't know how to show that it is not coercive, that is, that the reverse inequality does not hold.

Comment: Also, what's the difference with the $C^1$ case? Why is it coercive then?

Comment: To see that it is not coercive in $W^{1,2}$, you can look at a minimizing sequence. In the $C^1$ case it is also not coercive.

Comment: I considered the sequence $u_n = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\arctan(x/n)}{2\arctan(1/n)}$ to show that the minimum is not achieved. How does this help with coercivity?

Comment: What is the $W^{1,2}$-norm of this sequence?